# Filter query with or without keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a table with a name column and category_id column. The query below returns a `BadRequest` error. I think this is the most meaningful returned from the error blob.

*note: `"something*"` is a keyword I pass in to search for.

```
Expected field name but got START_OBJECT
```

I am looking for a query that will return results filtered by `category_id` with or without a keyword search.

```
{
  query: {
    bool: {must: [{
      wildcard: {name: "something*"}
    ]},
    filtered: {
      filter: {
        bool: {
          must: {
            term: {category_id: 1}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  sort: [{
    _geo_distance: {
      store_location: {:lat=>0, :lon=>0},
      order: "asc",
      unit: "miles"
    }
  }]
}
```

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: mysql? dont think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to guess (ie. this is untested), I'd say it's because you've got your bool outside of your `filtered` sub-query. Move it inside a `query` sub-query inside your `filtered` sub-query like so:

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {
      query: {
        bool: {must: [{
          wildcard: {name: "something*"}
        ]},
      },
      filter: {
        bool: {
          must: {
            term: {category_id: 1}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  sort: [{
    _geo_distance: {
      store_location: {:lat=>0, :lon=>0},
      order: "asc",
      unit: "miles"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: The query was processed but I get zero results back. I have data with `category_id: 1` I am expecting. However, this query is not returning any results.